# linearly interpolate and determine gradients for data on non-uniform grid

Tags: interpolation, scipy, delaunay-triangulation

I have measurements of a quantity on a 3d grid. My measurements are distributed on four x-y planes similar to what is shown in the image below. The measurements roughly follow a Cartesian grid but have varying spacing and gaps. The measurements are more sparse in the z-direction but I expect the quantity to vary by an order of magnitude more in the x and y direction.

The whole domain is not convex but for now I will concentrate only on the subset of data points where the measurement planes overlap.

[image: data positions]

I am interested in linearly interpolating the quantity in 3D (in the x-y region where the measurement planes overlap), integrating the quantities over all space, and determining gradients in each direction.

I am aware of trilinear interpolation along a cartesian grid (e.g. scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator) and barycentric interpolation with Delaunay triangulation (e.g. scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator). Is there an advantage to choosing one method over another?
I also found a gradient calculation in matplotlib.tri.TriInterpolator.gradient. Is this a good choice?

Comment: Is your domain convex? It does not seem so in your image.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try kriging.  See [Connor Johnson's example](http://connor-johnson.com/2014/03/20/simple-kriging-in-python/) and the [pyKriging](http://pykriging.com/) package.

Comment: @nicoguaro I updated the question that for now I only want to concentrate on the subset of points where the planes overlap.